# Angular Mat-Select not selecting stored value

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I am using angular 8, angular material and reactive forms.

My form is using a mat-select and getting its options from an array. When I create a new object it works fine and the options are displayed as expected. However, when editing this object (using the same form) it is not grabbing the object value for some reason.

For example:
I have a doctor array with id, firstName and lastName.

```
{
  id: 4,
  firstName: Jimmy,
  lastName: Jones
}
```

The mat-form-field looks like this:

```
<form fxLayout="column" [formGroup]="patientForm">
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex>
  <mat-label>Doctor</mat-label>
  <mat-icon matSuffix class="secondary-text">developer_board</mat-icon>
  <mat-select formControlName="doctor" placeholder="Select Doctor">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let doc of doctors" [value]="doc.id">
      {{doc.first_name}}{{doc.last_name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
</form>
```

My TS file

```
...
doctors: Doctor[];
constructor() {
        // Set the defaults
        this.action = _data.action;

        if (this.action === 'edit') {
            this.dialogTitle = 'Edit Patient';
            this.patient = _data.patient;
        }
        else {
            this.dialogTitle = 'New Patient';
            this.patient = new Patient({});
        }

        this._doctorsService.getDoctors().then(
            doctors => this.doctors = doctors
        );

        this.patientForm = this.createPatientForm();
}


createPatientForm(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
        id: [this.patient.id],
        doctor: [this.patient.doctor]
    });
}
```

The issue is that I want this field to select the doctor with the ID 4 on load but it is not showing any selection at all (just showing the placeholder). The doctor is in the list it is just not being selected by default.

I am sure this is something silly that i am doing but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
jAC

Comment: Try removing .ID in your [Value]

Comment: Hi @TheGrandJ i have tried removing the .id but i still have the same issue where it is not selecting the value that is in the object being passed.

Comment: @JohnPeters unfortunately that does not help as i am using reactive forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was totally something silly and I hope this helps someone struggling with the same problem.

The api i was consuming was actually presenting the data for doctor as the "name" field rather than the ID. However, when i was saving data it was expecting an ID for the doctor, not the name. Saving the data worked fine as i was passing the ID on selection but the drop down couldn't match the selected item over as it was expecting an ID but getting the name.

I switched the api to use the ID and everything started working as expected. I would guess if i had switched Angular to use the name that would have worked as well except the API was concatenating the first and last name, so it wouldn't match on the API side.

Lessons learned. Thanks for the advice from those above!

Answer (score 0):

Mat-Select have **value** property you can use this property to set a default value like this

```
<mat-select formControlName="doctor" placeholder="Select Doctor" [(value)]="selectValue">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let doc of doctors" [value]="doc.id">
   {{doc.first_name}}{{doc.last_name}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

you can change your selection like this by assigning id to **selectValue** variable

please click [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-object?file=app%2Fselect-form-example.ts) for live example

Comment: I am using reactive forms so this example does not work for me. The odd part is, that i have this working on another form with the same set up. So i am not sure what is going on here. It has got to be something silly im doing.